# Why can't mypy distinguish between Qt widget types in a Generic python class?

Tags: python, pyside2, type-hinting, mypy

I'm using a wrapper object in my program and making it a Generic to detect incompatible uses for some function calls.  The snippet below demonstrates how mypy can report an error if a bool wrapper is used as an argument to a function that takes an int wrapper.

```
CtrlType = TypeVar('CtrlType')
class Wrapper(Generic[CtrlType]):
    def __init__(self, value: CtrlType):
        self.value = value

    def get(self) -> CtrlType:
        return self.value

def squared(value: Wrapper[int]):
    return value.get() * value.get()

not_an_int: Wrapper[bool] = Wrapper(False)
squared(not_an_int)  # mypy reports incompatible-type error here
```

But this does not work with Qt widget classes

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QCheckBox
def line_edit_only(value: Wrapper[QLineEdit]):
    pass
line_edit_only(Wrapper(QCheckBox()))  # no error reported here
line_edit_only(QCheckBox())  # no error for this either
line_edit_only(bool) # error is reported here though
```

Can anyone explain why mypy cannot detect the error for the wrong Generic type if it's derived from QWidget?

Comment: Have checked what MyPy reports for ``reveal_type(QLineEdit)``? Usually, the problem is that these types are untyped, i.e. aliases for ``Any``.

Comment: This seems to be a bug/limitation in pyside2, since the same example works as expected when using pyqt5 (i.e. mypy reports three errors). Judging by the comments on [PYSIDE-1100](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1100), their mypy support may still be a work in progress, so I suggest you take this up with the pyside devs.